# (Unity 3D) (C# Scripts) UI Button that links to next scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry, I do not have any code to provide, as I do not know if this requires any code, it may just need a simple property change in inspector or something.
I am not sure, though, which is why I'm asking you people.
Basically, I have a main menu, as scene 1, then scene 2 is the 'spawn' part of the 'game'.
On the main menu, I want the 'play' button to bring the 'player' to scene 2.
I am using the latest version of Unity, and the project is 3D.
Any answers is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (buttonPressed)
    Application.LoadLevel("Scene 2");
```

Just make sure `"Scene 2"` is included in your build options

Comment: Alright. It won't let me mark as answer for another 11 minutes. Gonna go try it now, I am sure it will work though, I trust this site a lot.